# Cannot load type from assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

I'm studying this code from [MSDN MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) I couldn't figure out why this is throwing an exception. I'm thinking if it could be the Worker type is in the same assembly as the class Program? Do I need to install this assembly in the GAC, though I'm running this in debug mode in Visual Studio 2017 editor. I don't have a solid understanding of how to work with assembly.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AppDomainMarshalByRefObject
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Worker localWorker = new Worker();
            localWorker.PrintDomain();

            AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
            Worker remoteWokrer = (Worker)ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Worker).Assembly.FullName, "Worker");

            remoteWokrer.PrintDomain();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void PrintDomain()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object is executing in AppDomain \"{0}\"",
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate an incomplete `typename`. Add this to your code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        var typeName = typeof(Worker);

        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
        Worker remoteWokrer = (Worker)ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Worker).Assembly.FullName, typeName.FullName);

        ...
    }
```